# your or you're?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Which one is correct? Why?
(a) The best gift God has given you was **you're** precious smile.
(b) The best gift God has given you was **your** precious mile.

Comment: `your` is correct. `you're` is just short for "you are" and "The best gift God has given you was you are precious smile." wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

***Your*** and ***You're*** are quite different things.

***Your*** is a pronoun possessive, *your house, your thoughts, your smile etc*. So this means your example 'b' is correct.

***You're*** is short for *you are*: e.g. *...you're very good looking*; *...you're a pain in the neck*; ...don't go until you're ready etc.

Answer (score 1):

"You're" is the contraction of "You are". "Your" is a possessive, like *my, his, her, our, their*. So, "you're" would be meaningless, and "your" appropriate.

Incidentally, the mix of present perfect and past simple in this sentence is not natural, but that's a separate issue

Answer (score 0):

B is the correct answer. The reason is simple: *you're* is a contraction (two words in one, with the addition of an apostrophe--'), and it means *you are*. Other contracted words include

> - Haven't = have not
> - Won't = will not
> - Wouldn't = would not
> - Didn't = did not
> - You'll = you will
> - Could've = could have
> - Hadn't = had not

*Your*, on the other hand, is a possessive pronoun which takes the place of, for example,

> - belonging to
> - the property of
> - not mine, but belonging to you

Why Americans are so fond of contractions, I do not (don't) know. When we hear people talking without them, however, we sit up and take notice. A case in point is the movie "True Grit," starring Jeff Bridges. Check it out!